# Can't save python pptx file

Tags: python, python-pptx

I manipulate an existing pptx file with python-pptx. Somehow I can't save my changes in the file. The manipulation works out well. To give an example: I can change the values in a table and when I read out the table I receive the new values. At the end of my script I use the "normal " prs.save(path) (with prs being an Presentation and path the directory and name of the file).
I Do not receive an error message. Anyhow, the changes are not saved. Anyone an idea about the reason for this strange behavior?

```py
path = r'/Users/mysel/Documents/test.pptx'
prs = Presentation(path)
# Some manipulation of the document
prs.save(path)
```

Comment: Does it work if you save using a different path?

Comment: That was my first idea, too. Unfortunately no.

Comment: Figured it out: I imported the Presentation function in another script which I imported in my original script. This caused the error.